# How to test if root user is enabled in Mac?

Tags: root, macintosh

I need to test if Mac root user is enabled or not.

I usually enable/disable it by using dsenableroot.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo dscl . -read /Users/root Password
```

If root is **enabled** it will output `Password: ********`, otherwise it will be just `No such key: Password`.

Edit: After Apple's security patch 2017 Nov 29, if root is disabled, it may output `Password: *`

---

Alternative:

```
sudo plutil -p /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist | grep -A 2 passwd
```

If the result is:

```
"passwd" => [
0 => "********"
]
```

Then root is **enabled**. If it's:

```
"passwd" => [
0 => "*"
]
```

then root is **disabled**.

Comment: And if the first one indicates that its enabled (with `Password: *` but only a single star) but the second one that its disabled?